# save uris output on console to file system

Tags: marklogic

How can I save the result from qconsole to output file.  The output.txt will has name uri in each line below.  I have over thousand of documents.

```
 Caltech.xml
 CGU.xml
 GMU.xml
 Hopkins.xml
 Georgetown.xml
 ....

let $uris:= cts:uris(
        (),
        (),
        cts:and-query(( cts:collection-query("/Universities/")))

    )

let $quote:=
   for $u in $uris
   return 
       fn:substring-after($u,"/Universities/")

let $output:=
text {
fn:concat(
    fn:string-join(($quote),","),
    "&#x0D;&#x0A;"
 )

}  
return xdmp:save(fn:concat("/09122018/output.txt") ,$output)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't string-join and concat to create one big string. Instead, hand in multiple strings as text nodes, wrapped in a document node that you pass into `xdmp:save`. You can easily handle a couple of million documents that way (provided you are willing to wait a minute). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52005868/918496

If you need to scale beyond that, look at [Corb2](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2), as suggested by Rob.

HTH!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [xdmp:save](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:save) to write a file to the filesystem MarkLogic Server is using.

For sets of data too large for QConsole to handle I recommend you look at [CORB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2).

Comment: but I want output.txt will be exactly likeCaltech.xml
 CGU.xml
 GMU.xml
 Hopkins.xml
 Georgetown.xml

Comment: Thank you.  I have to use "&#x000A;" a single newline character for each uri name